# Mapper not mapping properly - mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

i am having troubles mapping a nested dto field properly with mapstruct. i have a couple of dtos:

```
@Data
public class InstrumentGet {

    .....
    private MediaGet image;
    private List<LocaleGet> locales;

}
@Data
public class LocaleGet {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String iso6391;
    private boolean defaultLanguage;

}
@Data
public class MediaGet {
    private String uri;
    private int width;
    private int height;
}
```

With corresponding mappers

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface LocaleMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "culture.iso6391",target = "iso6391")
    @Mapping(source = "culture.defaultLanguage",target = "defaultLanguage")
    LocaleGet toDtoGet(BaseLocale locale);
    List<LocaleGet> toDtosGet(List<BaseLocale> locales);
}
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring")
public interface MediaMapper {

    MediaGet toDtoGet(Media media);
}
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",uses = {MediaMapper.class, LocaleMapper.class})
public interface InstrumentMapper {
    InstrumentGet instrumentToInstrumentGet(Instrument instrument, List<BaseLocale> locales);


}
```

So far everything works perfectly fine and the generated code autowires other needed mappers to build dtos properly. Eg. of the generated instrument mapper implementation

```
@Component
public class InstrumentMapperImpl implements InstrumentMapper {

    @Autowired
    private MediaMapper mediaMapper;
    @Autowired
    private LocaleMapper localeMapper;

    @Override
    public InstrumentGet instrumentToInstrumentGet(Instrument instrument, List<BaseLocale> locales) {
        if ( instrument == null && locales == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        InstrumentGet instrumentGet = new InstrumentGet();

        if ( instrument != null ) {
            instrumentGet.setDefaultName( instrument.getDefaultName() );
            instrumentGet.setImage( mediaMapper.toDtoGet( instrument.getImage() ) );
        }
        if ( locales != null ) {
            instrumentGet.setLocales( localeMapper.toDtosGet( locales ) );
        }

        return instrumentGet;
    }
}
```

Now i run into trouble when trying to create a mapper that has nested instrument dto inside of it. The mapper should use instrumentMapper to create the required dto properly. The dto:

```
@Data
    public class MemberGet {
        ......
        private MediaGet image;
        private InstrumentGet instrument;
        ......
    }
```

The mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",uses = {InstrumentMapper.class, MediaMapper.class})
public interface ClientMapper {

@Mapping(source = "member.band.uid",target = "bandUid")
MemberGet toDtoMemberGet(Member member,  List<BaseLocale> locales);

}
```

The generated code:

```
@Component
public class ClientMapperImpl implements ClientMapper {

    @Autowired
    private MediaMapper mediaMapper;

    @Override
    public MemberGet toDtoMemberGet(Member member, List<BaseLocale> locales) {
        if ( member == null && locales == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        MemberGet memberGet = new MemberGet();

        if ( member != null ) {
            memberGet.setBandUid( memberBandUid( member ) );
            memberGet.setPersonDetails( member.getPersonDetails() );
            memberGet.setBirthday( member.getBirthday() );
            memberGet.setGender( member.getGender() );
            memberGet.setImage( mediaMapper.toDtoGet( member.getImage() ) );
            memberGet.setInstrument( instrumentToInstrumentGet( member.getInstrument() ) );
        }

        return memberGet;
    }

    private String memberBandUid(Member member) {
        if ( member == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Band band = member.getBand();
        if ( band == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String uid = band.getUid();
        if ( uid == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return uid;
    }

    protected InstrumentGet instrumentToInstrumentGet(Instrument instrument) {
        if ( instrument == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        InstrumentGet instrumentGet = new InstrumentGet();

        instrumentGet.setDefaultName( instrument.getDefaultName() );
        instrumentGet.setImage( mediaMapper.toDtoGet( instrument.getImage() ) );

        return instrumentGet;
    }
}
```

Now the media mapper gets picked up fine and uses the required method, I am having problem with the Instrument mapper, mapstruct does not autowire and call the required method but instead creates its own method which does not suit my needs. I am obviously doing something wrong here. Could anyone give me a hint or any kind of suggestion?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limitation in mapstruct when it comes to using directly from another mapper a mapper that has several source parameters. You can test it by yourself by removing one of the two parameters of the referenced mapper.

Instead you can use **@BeforeMapping** or **@AfterMapping** or **decoractor** to resolve your issue.

Context parameter may also work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! i see what are you aiming at. I managed to do it, but the thing is that then i would need  to inject this after mapper in all of the classes that have instrument or anything else that does not get mapped. My question is why did the media dto get mapped and this no, is there anything specific that is obstructing it. Regards

Comment: @vibetribe93 Lets say that you have a mapper A that is using mapper B and mapper C. And mapper A has a mapping method that accepts multiple parameters lets say 3 parameters. String , Integer, Integer mapper B accepts String , Integer and mapper C again String , Integer. Lets say mapper B is interested only in the second paramneter of mapper A and mapper C is interested only in the third parameter. How do you know who is interested in what ? It is not that easy , is it ?

Comment: True. Just wanted to be sure about the reason! I will proceed with this setup. Regards